# dd-wrt on wap54G - multiple SSIDs work, until reboot, then brick...?

Tags: wireless-router, dd-wrt

I've had a few WAP54Gs that found some extra life with DD-WRT. Recently I added a few extra SSIDs to them (they had been running one each), which worked fine - until I rebooted one, and it stopped working (lights on, nobody home - resets had no effect.) The other had a power outage a few weeks later, same thing happened. These had worked for years after being DD-WRTed, and made no complaint about (and worked fine with) multiple SSIDs until the reboot/power cycle.

Given that they are *rather* obsolete 802.11g/b devices, it's not a burning question I need to solve ASAP (or quite possibly, ever - I swapped in newer n/g/b devices in both cases), but I'm curious if anyone else has run into this particular problem, and/or solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your devices got at least partly bricked.
You may have a look at [this debricking guide](http://www.linuxmediaserver.net/linux-basics/bricked-router).

The pinout of your router's serial port can be found [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Serial_port_pinouts#Linksys_WRT-54G.28S.2CL.29).
If you will solder a serial console port on it and connect using an USB<->serial converter, you would see the kernel messages etc. This info will help understand what's wrong and let you progress with fix ;)